# $\forall x > 0$, there exists a unique $\xi_x$ s.t.$ \int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt=xe^{\xi_x^2}$; solve $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\xi_x}{x} $

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

$$proof: \forall x > 0, \text{there exists a unique} \quad \xi_x \quad s.t. \int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt=xe^{\xi_x^2} ; \text{solve} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\xi_x}{x}  $$

my thought is to use the First mean value theorem for definite integrals to find the$\xi_x$ and assume another $\xi'_x$ to proof the existence and the uniqueness.But for the another problem my thought is
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln e^{(\frac{\xi_x}{x})^2 }=\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln(\int _{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt)^\frac{1}{x^2}$$

but after using L'Hopida's Law, I have no idea what to do next

Comment: Hint: use sandwiching: $\int_0^x e^{t^2}\mathrm{d}t$ is less than $xe^{x^2}$ and more than $e^{(x-1)^2}$. So $\sqrt{(x-1)^2-{\ln x}}<\xi_x<x$

Comment: Existence follows from the mean value theorem, and uniqueness from the fact that the derivative is strictly positive.

Comment: thanks a lot, sandwiching works well